# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TokenKind'

Tags: powershell, psreadline

I have beautified my Powershell according to [this blog](https://coolcode.org/2018/03/16/how-to-make-your-powershell-beautiful/), but the `Operator` and `Parameter` are grey as follows:

[image]
[image]

So I change their colors by `Set-PSReadlineOption`:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Operator -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

but get the following errors:

> Set-PSReadLineOption : **A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TokenKind'**。
>
> 所在位置 行:1 字符: 22
>
> - Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Operator -ForegroundColor Yellow
> - - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-PSReadLineOption]，ParameterBindingException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.SetPSReadLineOption

But the [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-5.1) documents of `Set-PSReadlineOption` shows that it has a `TokenKind` parameter which in turn can have `Operator` as its parameter.

I'm confused why this error happens.

My powershell version is

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They made a breaking change PSReadline V2, read about it here: https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/issues/738

So instead of

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind String -ForegroundColor Magenta
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Variable -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

You would do something like

```
$colors = @{}
$colors['String'] = [System.ConsoleColor]::Magenta
$colors['Variable'] = [System.ConsoleColor]::Cyan
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors $colors
```

I think there is a way to specify foreground/background color in the hashtable as well, but haven't figured out yet.

Read the Set-PSReadLineOption doc [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine#usage).

Comment: Thanks for your information! After reading the Issue 738, I find that `Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{Operator = "Yellow"; Parameter = "Yellow"; Command = "Blue";String = "DarkYellow"}` just works as I expected. Thanks again!